# Join property values of a list of objects in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

Is it possible to join the values of properties of a list of objects for displaying it?
Something like:

```
{{ users|join(', ', username) }}
```

Where `users` are objects, having a `getUsername()` method.
I suppose `join` doesn't take an additional argument, but is there a workaround to achieve something similar? I can not use the `__toString()` function, as it represents something else...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use..

```
{% set usernames = [] %}

{% for user in users %}
    {% set usernames = usernames|merge([user.username]) %}
{% endfor %}

{{ usernames|join(', ') }}
```

Not the prettiest though.

You could always make a custom twig filter to do it.

Comment: This way works for me, thanks you. But I wouldn't have accepted your answer if you didn't mention that it is not the prettiest way and I should try to use a custom filter instead, so thumbs up! I'll try to look into to the custom filter and post it here too.

Answer (score 14):

or have the same result with just one forloop

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.username }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use [map()](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/map.html) filter… and fit everything in one line:

```
{{ users|map(u => u.username)|join(', ') }}
```

Comment: Very elegant and pretty much the doc-refered use-case: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/map.html

Answer (score 2):

A shorter version of [digital-message's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41953055/1456376):

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.username ~ (not loop.last ? ', ') }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: very elegant love it!